# raspberry pi not allow ssh through port routing

Tags: linux, ssh, routes, raspberry-pi

I currently have my computer and Raspberry Pi sharing the same router but can not SSH into my pi. I set the pi up to allow port 23 as port 22 is already being used by my computer when i want to ssh into it from another location. I know that people say it is as simple as set up a port forwarding rule on the router and but am i missing something on the pi. I thought i had opened port 23 but maybe not. Any suggestions that you may have would be great so I can SSH into my pi without having a monitor present.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to change anything on the pi to allow ssh (assuming you didn't block ssh to begin with).

If you want to ssh to your pi from your computer, just connect to your pi's internal ip address.

If you want to ssh to your pi from outside your place, you need to use port forwarding.  So you'll want to create a rule for port 22 on your router to go to port 22 of your pi (internal ip address).  Then you just connect to your external ip address.

Side note:
When you ssh to your pi from your computer, your pi will use port 22, but your computer could be using any port between 49152 - 65535, it doesn't use port 22.

## EDIT:

Then you can forward port 23 of the router to port 22 of your pis internal ip address.  But when you connect to your pi from outside of your home, you will have to make sure the program you use to connect can change which port ssh connects to.  Because the default port will get forwarded to your computer.  So you will have an address like ssh xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:23.

Comment: But I am already using port 22 to forward to another computer on that local network. I didn't think you can have one port (22) forwarding to two different local IP's?